# SQL SUM up specific rows without subquery returning more than one row

Tags: sql, heidisql

There are a few posts that seem similar to this problem, but I cannot find the solution to this problem through those posts.

I have the following two tables that I am working with (I'm not posting the full table, just as much is needed to understand the problem):

Table 1: employee

| emp_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | Michael | Scott |
| 108 | Jim | Halpert |

Table 2: works_with

| emp_id | client_id | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 401 | 267,000 |
| 102 | 406 | 15,000 |
| 108 | 402 | 22,500 |
| 108 | 403 | 12,000 |

If this table data is not sufficient, I can go back and add more.

The issue I am having is with this code:

```
SELECT e.emp_id AS ID, 
e.first_name AS 'First Name', 
e.last_name AS 'Last Name', 
ww.total_sales = (SELECT SUM(ww.total_sales) 
                 FROM works_with
                 WHERE e.emp_id = ww.emp_id
                 ) AS Sales
FROM (employee e, works_with ww)
INNER JOIN works_with ON ww.emp_id = e.emp_id;
```

When I run the code like this, I get the error: "SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row."

I saw a solution online that said to add "Any" before the subquery, but this is the resulting table:

| ID | First Name | Last Name | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | Michael | Scott | 0 |

This is what I want the resulting table to look like:

| ID | First Name | Last Name | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | Michael | Scott | 282,000 |
| 108 | Jim | Halper | 34,500 |

I am confused as to how I would fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the results you need where table 1 is the first table you mentioned and table 2 is the second

```
SELECT
    T1.*
    SUM(T2.TOTAL_SALES)
FROM <TABLE1> T1
    JOIN <TABLE2> T2 ON T1.EMP_ID = T2.EMP_ID
GROUP BY
    T1.EMP_ID, T1.FIRST_NAME, T1.LAST_NAME
```